# How to get total annual sales

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API, I have used the code below to calculate Total Annual Sales (from `Transactions`):

```
private async Task<decimal> GetAllTotalMonthlyTransactions()
{
    string transactionMonth = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM");
    decimal totalMonthlyTransactions = 0;

    var sales = await _dbContext.Sales.ToListAsync();

    foreach (var item in sales)
    {
        var salesDate = item.CreatedAt.ToString();
        var salesMonth = salesDate.Substring(3, 2);

        if (transactionMonth == salesMonth)
        {
            totalMonthlyTransactions += item.Amount;
        }
    }

    return totalMonthlyTransactions;
}
```

How to I re-write the code above to get `TotalAnnualSales` (Transactions)?

Comment: What do you think `if (transactionMonth == salesMonth)` is doing

Comment: what year do you want the annual sales for the current one?

Comment: `saless` !== `sales`

Comment: Step through the code with a debugger and check your values. Don't use substrings if you don't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async Task<decimal> GetAllTotalMonthlyTransactions()
{
    decimal totalAnnualTransactions = 0;

    int _year  = DateTime.Now.Year;    
    var sales = await dbContext.Sales.Where(y=>y.CreatedAt.Year==_year).ToListAsync();

    // The first method
    foreach (var item in sales)
    {
         totalAnnualTransactions += item.Amount;
    }

    // The second method
    //double totalAnnualTransactions= sales.Sum(item => item.Amount);

    return totalAnnualTransactions;
}
```

Comment: you are using linq why not do the sum in the linq statement?

Comment: in the second method which has been commented I used the linq...

Comment: Exactly my point -- if you put it in the first await linq statement you don't need ToList().  ToList() if very expensive and not needed .

Comment: I thought the readability of the program would decrease. Otherwise, you are right

Comment: It is linq -- if someone does not know what .sum() does they need to study up.

Comment: The entire method can be replaced with `return dbContext.Sales.Where(y => y.CreatedAt.Year == DateTime.Now.Year).Sum(x => x.Amount);`, which is a big improvement in readability.

Answer (score 1):

```
private async Task<decimal> GetAllTotalMonthlyTransactions()
{
    int currentYear  = DateTime.Now.Year;

    return (await dbContext.Sales.Where(t=>t.CreatedAt.Year==currentYear).ToListAsync()).Sum(item=>item.Amount);

}
```

Comment: What is collected in the sum function? The "Amount" variable must be added ....

Comment: @hosseinsabziani -- no.  This is the best solution as it is the fastest.  There is not benefit to having an amount value just to return.  So this solution uses the least amount of resources.

Comment: @hosseinsabziani added the lamba to select amount. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the datetimes to strings, try accessing them as ints. You can do this with .Month or .Year respectively

Comment: And as a note, both of those return int. Otherwise if you are just looking to change it just enough to work, replace the "MM" with "yyyy", and replace salesDate.Substring(3, 2) with salesDate.Substring(6, 4)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate `from` and `to` date range based on a specified month, then query/filter sales data with these `from` and `to` date range, like below.

```
var date1 = DateTime.Now;
var days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(date1.Year, date1.Month);

var from = new DateTime(date1.Year, date1.Month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
var to = new DateTime(date1.Year, date1.Month, days, 23, 59, 59);          

var totalMonthlyTransactions = sales.AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.CreatedAt >= from && s.CreatedAt <= to).Select(s => s.Amount).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code will work for you...

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<object>> GetMonthlyTransactions(int year)
    {
        var starting = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).Date;
        var sales = await context.Sales.Where(f => f.SalesDate >= starting).Select(s => new
        {
            Date = s.SalesDate.ToString("MM-yyyy"),
            Amount = s.NetAmount
        }).ToListAsync();
        var finaldata = sales.GroupBy(s => s.Date, (d, a) => new { Date = d, Am = a }).Select(l => new
        {
            Date = l.Date,
            Amount = l.Am.Sum(h => h.Amount)
        });
        return finaldata;
       
    }
```